# How to add custom messages and services to ros_gz_bridge

Tags: gazebo, ros2, custom-message, gz-sim, ros-gazebo

I would like to add custom messages and services to the gazebo ros bridge. But I am not sure what the best approach would be and miss a bit of documentation on how to achieve this.

For the sake of this discussion, let's say I want to bridge the standard gz messages `Boolean` or `Double` to my custom stamped ros types `BoolStamped` or `Float64Stamped`.

I know the message types need to be known at compile time as described [in this talk](https://vimeo.com/showcase/9954564/video/767127300). However, the speaker also makes it sound 'easy enough' to add messages to it.

Best case, I would like to externalize this addition to my own package, but I suspect I need to fork the entire `ros_gz` repo and inject those additions directly into the `ros_gz_bridge` package so the native ros node `parameter_bridge` has knowledge of those types.

Regardless of each method, I fail to find direct documentation on how to do that or examples of it.

Has anybody done this before? Or can somebody familiar with the `ros_gz_bridge` package point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

if you are fine with the "Embedding ROS 2 in Gazebo" approach mentioned in the given talk, then you could create a gazebo system-plugin to bridge the messages/topics by adapting the following sources:

Create a header file for the plugin:

```
#ifndef GZ_ROS_BOUNDINGBOX_BRIDGE_SYSTEM_H
#define GZ_ROS_BOUNDINGBOX_BRIDGE_SYSTEM_H

#include <gz/sim/EventManager.hh>
#include <gz/sim/System.hh>
#include <gz/sim/SdfEntityCreator.hh>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "vision_msgs/msg/detection2_d_array.hpp"
#include <gz/transport.hh>
#include <gz/msgs.hh>

namespace demo::ros::gz::system {

    class BoundingBoxBridge : public ::gz::sim::System,
                              public ::gz::sim::ISystemConfigure{

    public:
        BoundingBoxBridge();

    public:
        void Configure(
                const ::gz::sim::Entity &_entity,
                const std::shared_ptr<const sdf::Element> &_element,
                ::gz::sim::EntityComponentManager &_ecm,
                ::gz::sim::EventManager &_eventManager) override;

    private:
        rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr ros_node;
        rclcpp::Publisher<vision_msgs::msg::Detection2DArray>::SharedPtr ros_bbs_pub0;
        rclcpp::Publisher<vision_msgs::msg::Detection2DArray>::SharedPtr ros_bbs_pub1;
        ::gz::transport::Node gz_node;

    private:
        void OnGzBoundingBoxes0(const ::gz::msgs::AnnotatedAxisAligned2DBox_V &msg);
        void OnGzBoundingBoxes1(const ::gz::msgs::AnnotatedAxisAligned2DBox_V &msg);
        std::list<vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesisWithPose> hypothesis_array_from_label(const std::string &label);
        std::string label_to_class_name(int class_id);
    };

}

#endif //GZ_ROS_BOUNDINGBOX_BRIDGE_SYSTEM_H
```

Create the source file:

```
#include "demo/ros/gz/system/boundingbox_bridge.h"

#include <gz/common/Console.hh>
#include <gz/sim/components.hh>
#include <gz/plugin/Register.hh>
#include <gz/sim/SdfEntityCreator.hh>
#include <memory>
#include <sdf/Model.hh>
#include <sdf/sdf.hh>
#include <cmath>
#include <gz/sim/System.hh>



#include <string>

namespace demo::ros::gz::system {

    GZ_ADD_PLUGIN(
            BoundingBoxBridge,
            ::gz::sim::System,
            BoundingBoxBridge::ISystemConfigure
    )

    BoundingBoxBridge::BoundingBoxBridge() {

    }

    void BoundingBoxBridge::Configure(const ::gz::sim::Entity &_entity,
                                  const std::shared_ptr<const sdf::Element> &_element,
                                  ::gz::sim::EntityComponentManager &_ecm,
                                  ::gz::sim::EventManager &_eventManager) {
        (void) _ecm;
        (void) _eventManager;
        ::gz::common::Console::dbg << "Configure BoundingBoxBridge system" << std::endl;
        (void) _entity;
        (void) _element;
        if (!rclcpp::ok()) {
            rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);
        }
        this->ros_node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("boundingbox_bridge_system");
        this->ros_bbs_pub0 = this->ros_node->create_publisher<vision_msgs::msg::Detection2DArray>("/demo/gz/sense/camera_left/detection", 10);
        this->ros_bbs_pub1 = this->ros_node->create_publisher<vision_msgs::msg::Detection2DArray>("/demo/gz/sense/camera_right/detection", 10);
        gz_node.Subscribe("/demo/sense/camera_0/bounding_boxes", &BoundingBoxBridge::OnGzBoundingBoxes0, this);
        gz_node.Subscribe("/demo/sense/camera_1/bounding_boxes", &BoundingBoxBridge::OnGzBoundingBoxes1, this);

    }

    void BoundingBoxBridge::OnGzBoundingBoxes0(const ::gz::msgs::AnnotatedAxisAligned2DBox_V &_msg) {
        vision_msgs::msg::Detection2DArray ros_msg;

        std_msgs::msg::Header header;
        header.stamp.sec = (int)_msg.header().stamp().sec();
        header.stamp.nanosec = _msg.header().stamp().nsec();
        header.frame_id = "camera_left_optical";
        ros_msg.header = header;
        for (int i = 0; i < _msg.annotated_box_size(); i++) {
            const auto& gz_bb = _msg.annotated_box(i);
            vision_msgs::msg::Detection2D ros_bb;
            ros_bb.header = header;
            ros_bb.id = gz_bb.label();
            ros_bb.bbox.size_x = gz_bb.box().max_corner().x() - gz_bb.box().min_corner().x();
            ros_bb.bbox.size_y = gz_bb.box().max_corner().y() - gz_bb.box().min_corner().y();
            ros_bb.bbox.center.position.x = gz_bb.box().min_corner().x() + ros_bb.bbox.size_x / 2.0;
            ros_bb.bbox.center.position.y = gz_bb.box().min_corner().y() + ros_bb.bbox.size_y / 2.0;
            auto hypothesis = hypothesis_array_from_label(label_to_class_name(gz_bb.label()));
            ros_bb.results.insert(ros_bb.results.end(), hypothesis.begin(), hypothesis.end());
            ros_msg.detections.push_back(ros_bb);
        }
        this->ros_bbs_pub0->publish(ros_msg);
    }

    void BoundingBoxBridge::OnGzBoundingBoxes1(const ::gz::msgs::AnnotatedAxisAligned2DBox_V &_msg) {
        vision_msgs::msg::Detection2DArray ros_msg;

        std_msgs::msg::Header header;
        header.stamp.sec = (int)_msg.header().stamp().sec();
        header.stamp.nanosec = _msg.header().stamp().nsec();
        header.frame_id = "camera_right_optical";
        ros_msg.header = header;
        for (int i = 0; i < _msg.annotated_box_size(); i++) {
            const auto& gz_bb = _msg.annotated_box(i);
            vision_msgs::msg::Detection2D ros_bb;
            ros_bb.header = header;
            ros_bb.id = gz_bb.label();
            ros_bb.bbox.size_x = gz_bb.box().max_corner().x() - gz_bb.box().min_corner().x();
            ros_bb.bbox.size_y = gz_bb.box().max_corner().y() - gz_bb.box().min_corner().y();
            ros_bb.bbox.center.position.x = gz_bb.box().min_corner().x() + ros_bb.bbox.size_x / 2.0;
            ros_bb.bbox.center.position.y = gz_bb.box().min_corner().y() + ros_bb.bbox.size_y / 2.0;
            auto hypothesis = hypothesis_array_from_label(label_to_class_name(gz_bb.label()));
            ros_bb.results.insert(ros_bb.results.end(), hypothesis.begin(), hypothesis.end());
            ros_msg.detections.push_back(ros_bb);
        }
        this->ros_bbs_pub1->publish(ros_msg);
    }

    std::list<vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesisWithPose> BoundingBoxBridge::hypothesis_array_from_label(const std::string &label) {
        std::list<vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesisWithPose> hypothesis_array;

        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesisWithPose hypothesis_with_pose_blue_small;
        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesis hypothesis_blue_small;
        hypothesis_blue_small.class_id = "blue_small";
        hypothesis_blue_small.score = label == "blue_small" ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        hypothesis_with_pose_blue_small.hypothesis = hypothesis_blue_small;
        hypothesis_array.push_back(hypothesis_with_pose_blue_small);

        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesisWithPose hypothesis_with_pose_yellow_small;
        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesis hypothesis_yellow_small;
        hypothesis_yellow_small.class_id = "yellow_small";
        hypothesis_yellow_small.score = label == "yellow_small" ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        hypothesis_with_pose_yellow_small.hypothesis = hypothesis_yellow_small;
        hypothesis_array.push_back(hypothesis_with_pose_yellow_small);

        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesisWithPose hypothesis_with_pose_orange_small;
        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesis hypothesis_orange_small;
        hypothesis_orange_small.class_id = "orange_small";
        hypothesis_orange_small.score = label == "orange_small" ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        hypothesis_with_pose_orange_small.hypothesis = hypothesis_orange_small;
        hypothesis_array.push_back(hypothesis_with_pose_orange_small);

        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesisWithPose hypothesis_with_pose_orange_large;
        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesis hypothesis_orange_large;
        hypothesis_orange_large.class_id = "orange_larger";
        hypothesis_orange_large.score = label == "orange_larger" ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        hypothesis_with_pose_orange_large.hypothesis = hypothesis_orange_large;
        hypothesis_array.push_back(hypothesis_with_pose_orange_large);

        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesisWithPose hypothesis_with_pose_undefined;
        vision_msgs::msg::ObjectHypothesis hypothesis_undefined;
        hypothesis_undefined.class_id = "undefined";
        hypothesis_undefined.score = label == "undefined" ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        hypothesis_with_pose_undefined.hypothesis = hypothesis_undefined;
        hypothesis_array.push_back(hypothesis_with_pose_undefined);

        return hypothesis_array;
    }

    std::string BoundingBoxBridge::label_to_class_name(int class_id) {
        switch (class_id) {
            case 0:
                return "blue_small";
            case 1:
                return "yellow_small";
            case 2:
                return "orange_small";
            case 3:
                return "orange_larger";
            default:
                return "undefined";
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the plugin to the robot (or to the world, depending on use case):

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="demo">
    <gazebo reference="demo"/>
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="BoundingBoxBridge"
                name="demo::ros::gz::system::BoundingBoxBridge">
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
...
```

Add the plugin to the CMakeLists.txt for compilation:

```
add_library(BoundingBoxBridge SHARED src/system/boundingbox_bridge.cpp)
target_include_directories(BoundingBoxBridge PUBLIC include ${RCLCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(BoundingBoxBridge
        gz-plugin2
        gz-sim7
        gz-sensors7
        )
ament_target_dependencies(BoundingBoxBridge
        rclcpp
        nav_msgs
        geometry_msgs
        interface_ros
        visualization_msgs
        vision_msgs
        )
install(TARGETS BoundingBoxBridge DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

And finally register the required hooks (as shown in the talk):

1. In the CMakeLists.txt

```
ament_environment_hooks("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hooks/${PROJECT_NAME}.dsv.in")
ament_environment_hooks("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hooks/${PROJECT_NAME}.sh.in")
```

2. In the "hooks/gz_ros.dsv.in" file

```
prepend-non-duplicate;GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH;lib/@PROJECT_NAME@/
```

3. In the "hooks/gz_ros.sh.in" file:

```
ament_prepend_unique_value GZ_SIM_PLUGIN_PATH "$AMENT_CURRENT_PREFIX/lib/@PROJECT_NAME@"
```

In this example gazebo messages of type
gz::msgs::AnnotatedAxisAligned2DBox_V
are bridged to
vision_msgs::msg::Detection2DArray
by subscribing to the corresponding gazebo topic and registering a callback which publishes the converted messages via the embedded ros2 node.

This is done for the bounding boxes given by two different boundingbox_camera sensors attached to the robot.

In a similar way you could create a ros2-service with the embedded node and then redirect the service call to gazebo messages or interact with the simulation in a different way.

I originally created this system-plugin for a gazebo garden simulation test with ros2-humble some time ago.

Comment: I am so sorry about the late reply! Thank you for your answer and indeed this works and was my way forward in the end. However, I would have preferred to use the `ros_gz_bridge` api and do it ros independent. I had hoped to get a hold of any author of the `ros_gz_bridge` repository here, since it seems so easy to just add a mapping  (at the first glance).